# HttpWebResponse Close() method

Tags: c#, .net

Do I need to invoke Close method or some another cleaning on instance of HttpWebResponse class after I've used it.  I'm not accessing response stream but only headers and status code of the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You don't know its internals which means you can't know it is safe *not* to dispose it.

Comment: yes, it helped to solve my problem so it's true even if I'm accessing only headers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to close it.. scoping it with using clause is the best practice under such circumstances.